# Derivative of an expression

Tags: calculus

I completely forgot how to find derivatives, can someone give me an example of a simple equation and how to find its derivative? The only thing I remember is that the formula is$$f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ Thanks for the help.

Comment: $f'(x)$ is the *limit* of the fraction as $h$ tends to $0$.

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/education/math/calculus/the-basic-differentiation-rules/

Comment: @Spencer Thanks, that helped to jog my memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy example would be the derivative of $x^2+2x-1$.

The formula for finding derivatives, as you said, $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$
After substituting $x^2+2x+1$ into the formula, you get $$f'(x)=\frac{x^2+2hx+h^2-2h+2x+2h-1-x^2-2x+1}h=$$ $$f'(x)=\frac{h^2+2hx+2h}h=$$ $$h+2x+2$$
You find the equation as $h\rightarrow0$, so you substitute $0$ for $h$ and you get the answer: $$2x+2$$

Comment: In both the question and this answer there's a limit missing in the first equation. The derivative isn't the difference quotient.

Comment: @EthanBolker Oops, I recognized the formula OP wrote so I got a bit confused. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I remembered how to do it, but thanks anyway